# Dynamic labels using chart.js

Tags: javascript, json, charts

We have a huge bulk of json data with more than 1000 entries and we are trying to plot a line/bar chart for the same. However, as expected, with these huge entries the labels gets overlapped and we hardly could see anything.

**Is it possible to configure the step value of labels in the graph?**

The graph would actually be sorted based on dates and shows a month of data and we just want to show say for example 6 dates (every 5th date). I know this could be done programmatically by grouping the json data as and when required, however, we are just wondering whether there is a standard solution available for the same.

My code:

```
var line_chart = {
    labels : labelsX, // contains all the labels
    datasets : [

      {
        fillColor : "rgba(151,187,205,0.5)",
        strokeColor : "rgba(151,187,205,0.8)",
        highlightFill : "rgba(151,187,205,0.75)",
        highlightStroke : "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
        data : chartjsData // contains the value
      }
    ]
  }
 window.onload = function(){
    var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");
    window.myLine = new Chart(ctx).Line(line_chart, {
      responsive: true
     });
  }
```

Comment: it still does not work even I put the exactly the same statement....

Comment: did you by any chance got and answer for this? I had a similar issue.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36188205/dynamically-modifying-x-axis-label-for-bar-chart-in-chart-js

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how's your labels and values stands right now, but they should be arrays in this way:

```
labelsX = ["January", "February", "March"];
chartjsData  = [40, 10, 20];
```

The arrays in this way should work. hope this will help.

Comment: @Gotham'sReckoning it's been removed